# Kubernetes with AzureFile and other StorageEndpointSuffix

Tags: kubernetes

I try to mount an azure storage account (in Azure germany) in a Kubernetes pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: storagetest
spec:
 containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
 volumes:
      - name: azure
        azureFile:
          secretName: azure-secret
          shareName: clusterstorage
          readOnly: false
```

I created the azure-secret with the following file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azure-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname:base64AccoutnName
  azurestorageaccountkey: base64Key
```

When I start the pod, I get the following error message:

```
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a8a3e443-2135-11e8-8482-0017fa10471a/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/azure --scope -- mount -t cifs -o username=clusterstorage,password=***,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,vers=3.0 //....file.core.windows.net/... /var/lib/kubelet/pods/...volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/azure
Output: Running scope as unit run-....scope.
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I noticed the volume url to be xxx.file.core.windows.net and my endpoint address end with file.core.cloudapi.de.

Then I found the source code of [Azure File](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/volume/azure_file/azure_file.go) and saw the hard coded suffix there.

How can I change the suffix to use Kubernetes' AzureFile in Azure Germany?